# Python Simple Websocket Server doesn't work when I define the websocket class constructor

Tags: python, websocket, constructor

I'm using a [this simple websocket module](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server) in my code and I want my server to send the client some data (E.g. current time) every n seconds. my code is as below.

```
import threading
import datetime

from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket


# ============================================================================

class SimpleWS(WebSocket):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleWS, self).__init__() 
        threading.Timer(10.0, self.print_date).start()

    def handleMessage(self):
        print(self.address, 'sent massage')

    def handleConnected(self):
#         threading.Timer(10.0, self.print_date).start()
         print(self.address, 'connected')

    def handleClose(self):
        print(self.address, 'closed')  

    def print_date(self):
        threading.Timer(10.0, self.print_date).start()
        print str(datetime.datetime.now())


# ============================================================================

server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8080, SimpleWS)
server.serveforever()
```

The websocket server doesn't work using the above code. However if I remove the constructor, It works perfectly.

So my question is what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried Django Channels?

Comment: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-django-channels/

Comment: @MohammadAli No I haven't tried channels. It seems it's a more reliable module. I'll give it a try. Thank you.